# How can I implement relational database tables into MongoDB collections, keeping the functionality, using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have created MVC project with database using Entity Framework Core and SQL Server with the following relations as shown in the picture .It is simple enough for me to implement this with classes in C# and EFC. But I want to train and learn how to create/implement the same but using MongoDB and MongoDb.Driver. What will be the difference in building the Entities? What properties shall I use to tell MongoDb that I want exactly that connection between each Collection? As I know MongoDb does not rely on relations between the collections... Please help me understand how to implement One-Many, Many-Many, using my problem in MongoDb.[See the Table Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExAOP.png)

I managed to create ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole, who can signin into the application.
ApplicationUser inherits from IdentityUser same with ApplicationRole, using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
Each Signed In user is given a role. That works well so far and using Compass i can see that i write data in my database with proper connections between Users and their Roles.
Somehow I need to tell that each FootballManager and Player is ApplicationUser with specific role and this must be in the context of MongoDB as non-relational database. Further more need to implement the rest entities/collections - part of the whole database.
Later I intend to use most of this code to implement into WebAPI, using MongoDb and C#.

Comment: If that is for learning what do you expect to learn using a document oriented database as if its a relational database? That it doesn't fit well?

Comment: I would like to learn how to represent those table which have some relations in a different  environment, so if i need to use MongoDb - how would I implement logically these relations without being explicitly written as it can be done in EFC + C# where i can declare Foreign Keys and Primary Keys. I though there was a way to do that in case i use (want to use) Mongo Db. Imagine that my project is limited to that database - need to have some option to do that not only in SQL Server and other RDB structures.